# jquery in rails: changing color of textbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using jquery with rails... following code is my jquery code for color changing of textbox border.. I am using bootstrap components to do so.

```
    $("#user_password").change(function(){
var myapp = $("#user_password").val().length;
      if(myapp <= 6){
        $("#example").addClass("has-error");
      }else{
        $("#example").addClass("");
      }
    });
```

when i run this code, i get red color on the border when i type less or equal to 6 characters in associated textbox and i get no color when i type more than 6 characters.

But once i type less than 6 characters lets say 3 characters and click away textbox becomes red but when i add more characters to it let say 4 characters i still get red color but the sum is 7. I should be getting no color.
whereas when I insert 7 characters at start and remove 4 characters from it i am able to see red color which is correct but vice versa is not true for my case... Can anyone see what is the problem in this code? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using addClass, if you want to remove it, use removeClass:

```
 $("#example").removeClass("has-error");
```

Comment: Thanx... i forgot about this.. thanx a ton ... :)